# BadTokenException when trying to display fullscreen HTML5 video

Tags: android

I'm trying to allow a YouTube video within a WebView to display at fullscreen. The problem is, a second or so after the video shows, the app crashes with a BadTokenException.

I'm using the code pretty much line for line from here: 
[Android WebView with an embedded youtube video, full screen button freezes video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763483/android-webview-with-an-embedded-youtube-video-full-screen-button-freezes-video)

The only thing I changed was to let it match my activity and my view. It runs fine (without showing the video) if I comment out the line that sets the content view.

I've also tried the code from here:
http://shashikawlp.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/play-html5-video-on-android-webview/

But I get the same issue.

Here's the stack from the debugger:

```
ViewRootImpl.setView(View, WindowManager$LayoutParams, View) line: 661  
WindowManagerImpl.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams, CompatibilityInfoHolder, boolean) line: 326 
WindowManagerImpl.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams, CompatibilityInfoHolder) line: 224  
WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(View, ViewGroup$LayoutParams) line: 149 
HTML5VideoFullScreen$FullScreenMediaController(MediaController).show(int) line: 338 
HTML5VideoFullScreen$FullScreenMediaController(MediaController).show() line: 298    
HTML5VideoFullScreen$FullScreenMediaController.show() line: 374 
HTML5VideoFullScreen.onPrepared(MediaPlayer) line: 220  
MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 2071  
MediaPlayer$EventHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
```

Any ideas why the FullScreenMediaController isn't getting a proper window context to create itself on, which appears to be the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The webview was inside of a pager. The previous developer was passing the application context to the pager instead of the activity context and I didn't realize it. Switching it over to the activity context fixed the problem.