# YouTube Video fullscreen WebView

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, fullscreen

I'm working on an app based on WebView. 
The main goal is to watch YouTube videos. 
My issue is that I'm not able to see the videos on a fullscreen mode but I have to open the YouTube app... 
Can anyone help me please?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private WebView mWebView; 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

 WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

 }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763483/android-webview-with-an-embedded-youtube-video-full-screen-button-freezes-video

Comment: I tried to implements but without results...