# Jquery open video in fullscreen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, video, popup

I have a video that I would like to open in fullscreen on click of the thumbnail.
Following is my code

```
<a href="#videoDiv" data-rel="popup"> 
    <img src="imageThumbnail.jpg" onClick="selectVideo(1)" >
</a>
<div id="videoDiv" data-role="popup"class="ui-content"></div>

 function selectVideo(id) {
   var videolist = getvideos()[id];
   if (videolist) {
    se$("#videoDiv").html(videolist.url);
   }
 }
```

The videolist.url returns an string like this

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hVfYVNALIS0?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

How can I make the video play fullscreen directly when clicked on thumbnail?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-Full Screen for a Youtube embed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615380/auto-full-screen-for-a-youtube-embed)

Comment: the videos maybe from either youtube or vimeo.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this but for local/selfhosted .mp4 videos. @jsp