# How can I allow fullscreen for youtube iframes within a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, youtube, fullscreen

I'm building a chrome extension that has some embedded videos available. I'd like for them to be able to go fullscreen, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I've tried based on some other post's resolutions. Yet still clicking full screen doesn't do anything.

```
 <iframe width="468" height="263" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KnzFc0ln2do?rel=0&fs=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You can do it without Youtube API by adding the PHP variable `&autoplay=1` to the `src` attribute of your `<iframe>`. Follow up this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456453/how-to-add-a-button-to-play-youtube-video-full-screen-using-javascript

Comment: @Gui47 I tried to code you linked without success. The video just autoplays without going fullscreen.

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: @gui47 When I click the 'Play in fullscreen' button, the video beings playing but doesn't go fullscreen. This is an embedded video within a chrome extension. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: When you inspect popup in the console, any error is showing up?

Comment: @gui47 The only error I get is a failed to load resources one, which looks unrelated to the video.