# Youtube + Selenium ChromeDriver (Python) - How to know when a video ends?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

[Edit: solved, see mid-way in text of question]

Quick question on understanding the contents of a Youtube page with a video playing in it:

**In summary**

I use Selenium to play videos on Youtube, as part of a browser-based GUI.

I need to know when the video has finished playing, for the GUI to do something else (e.g. feed local HTML into the browser).

**Code snippet and question**

```
import os, time
from selenium import webdriver

# [...]
chromedriver = 'path_to_chromedriver_binary'  # substitute as appropriate
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
youtube_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=somevideo'
driver.get(youtube_link)
```

At this point, I could `time.wait()` for the length of the video.

However, I wonder if I could query the YouTube page via the Selenium driver and gauge the time remaining for the play-through in a while loop (I am not familiar with how to extract this info from a youtube page)

Thanks!

**[Edits with solution]**

**Selenium Solution**

Thanks to Stanjer, and to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium), you can get the `movie_player` status through this method:

```
player_status = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('movie_player').getPlayerState()")
```

(don't forget to add "return" at the beginning of the script)

**Selenium Alternative Solution**

Less elegant but worth pointing out: 
`driver.text` returns a string representing the video timer in this string format '1:00 / 2:00'. Therefore you can check if the video has played through by something along these lines:

```
video_is_playing = True
while video_is_playing:
    time.sleep(1)
    video_is_playing = not(driver.text[:4] == driver.text[-4:])
```

[edit] As per Jose's comment, this info can also be accessed by:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text
```

**Complication and next question**

I need to open up the video in maximised format, and with autoplay.

This means I call the following url:

```
youtube.com/v/<video_code>?rel=0&autoplay=1
```

However this returns a very short html which only contains an embed code, as per example here:

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
    <BODY leftMargin=0 scroll=no topMargin=0>
        <EMBED height="100%" 
        type=application/x-shockwave-flash 
        width="100%" 
        src=https://www.youtube.com/v/Fsc-oT9PsSQ?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1
        fullscreen="yes">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So I have no `movie_player` element here.

Approach 1 - can I extract the timer from the `application/x-shockwave-flash`?

Approach 2 - If I launch the youtube video in a classic Youtube page, how can I tell the `movie_player` to maximise itself?

(note: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114884/make-youtube-video-fullscreen-using-iframe-and-javascript-api) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615380/auto-full-screen-for-a-youtube-embed) probably contain info to solve approach 2, will post if I get this to work with Selenium)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can execute javascript API in context of youtube video page:

```
youtubePlayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
youtubePlayer.getPlayerState();
```

So according to https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1

`state == 0` is when a video has ended

You can add an executor in a loop checking the state every N seconds.

You can also use the 'onStateChange' function of the Youtube iFrame API to print whenever the state changes.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      console.log(player.getPlayerState());     // 1 = Playing || 2 = Paused || 3 = <<- O ->> || 0 = Finished.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of video and current playing time as text and then convert them into seconds. Also, as a loop you can wait until the current time reaches the length of the video.

```
length_str = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-duration").text
current_time_str = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text

import re
length = re.findall(r'\d+', length_str) # convert ['2:24'] to ['2', '24']
current_time = re.findall(r'\d+', current_time_str)

length_sec = 60 * int(length[0]) + int(length[1])
current_time_sec = (60 * int(current_time[0]) + int(current_time[1]))
remaining_time = length_sec - current_time_sec
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text
```

it only works while the time and title are shown on the screen. Once a couple of seconds past, the titles disappears and the returned value is "".

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Just add the wait for `Replay` button:

```
video_ends = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ytp-chrome-controls button[title=Replay]")
```

Works in Chrome.