# How to make Selenium WebDriver to wait for HTML5 video (jwplayer) completion?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html5-video, jwplayer

I want to close the driver corresponding to the video whenever it is finished, but I happen not to find how to listen for the video completion through Selenium WebDriver (in Java).

My video is launched through a `driver.get(file://path//player.html);` command, and the jwplayer is coded in javascript..

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following link. This could be useful to you. Feel free to ask any doubts.

[Youtube + Selenium (Python) - How to know when video ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706101/youtube-selenium-python-how-to-know-when-video-ends)

Comment: Pretty Useful (+1) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your input. I already saw this post, but this video is from youtube and I have my own player. Additionally, I am not using Selenium with Python, rather Java.

Comment: Can you explain bit more about the player that you are working on and your approach? @Jackson

Comment: my player is an HTML5 file which has an embedded plug-in reporting information to a certain platform. I just open the HTML5 file and an mp4 video starts auto-playing. The player is coded in JavaScript.