# I can't make a specific "button" open a specific youtube "iframe"

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to make a web page (with Laravel) that, when pressing a button, opens a YouTube "iframe" in full screen and plays it, using the YouTube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference )

When I do it with only 1 button and 1 player, it works great, as shown in the following code.

```
    <h1>One-click play+fullscreen via YouTube API</h1>
Suggested code from this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/20289540/288906">StackOverflow answer</a>

<h2>Instructions</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Click on [play fullscreen]</li>
  <li>Click on the fullscreen button in youtube's player to exit fullscreen</li>
</ol>

<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<button>play fullscreen</button>
<div id="player" ></div>

<script>

var player, iframe;
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
console.log($('#player'));

// init player
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '300',
    videoId: 'Sq3wR__guNA',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

iframes=[];
// when ready, wait for clicks
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  iframes[0] = $('#player')

  setupListener(); 
}

function setupListener (){
$('button').addEventListener('click', playFullscreen);
}

function playFullscreen (){
  player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile
  console.log(player);
  var requestFullScreen = iframes[0].requestFullScreen || iframes[0].mozRequestFullScreen || iframes[0].webkitRequestFullScreen;

  if (requestFullScreen) {
    console.log(iframes[0]);
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframes[0])();
  }
}

</script>
```

The problem arises when I try to make button1 open player1
button2 open player2, and so on.

Here is the HTML code I am using, it is important to note that the data sent with "data-" correctly reaches the javascript file:

```
    <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table100">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="table100-head">
                            <th class="column1">To</th>
                            <th class="column2">Map</th>
                            <th class="column3">Description</th>
                            <th class="column4">Times voted</th>
                            <th class="column5">Times favorited</th>
                            <th class="column6">Rating</th>
                            <th class="column7">Video</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php $totalVideos = 12;?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">var totalVideos = <?php echo $totalVideos;?>;</script>
                        @foreach($plays as $play)
                            <!--Si es que se llego al video 12, dejan de crearse filas-->
                            @if ($loop->iteration > $totalVideos)

                                @break
                            @endif
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column1">{{$play->to}}</td>
                                <td class="column2">{{$play->map}}</td>
                                <td class="column3">{{$play->description}}</td>
                                <td class="column4">{{$play->timesvoted}}</td>
                                <td class="column5">{{$play->timesfavorited}}</td>
                                <td class="column6">{{$play->rating}}</td>
                                <td class="column7">
                                    <button id="button{{$loop->iteration}}">play fullscreen</button>
                                    <div id="player{{$loop->iteration}}" class="youtube-video" data-playId='{{$play->id}}' data-videoId='{{$play->videoId}}' data-startTime='{{$play->startTime}}' data-endTime='{{$play->endTime}}'></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<!-- Youtube plugin test -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/video-popup.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var data = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-video');

requestFullScreen();

function requestFullScreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
    console.log("Your browser can use fullscreen right now");
  } else {
    console.log('Your browser cannot use fullscreen right now');
  }
}

var playerConfigList=[];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var videoId = data[i].attributes[3].nodeValue;
  var startSeconds = data[i].attributes[4].nodeValue;   // set your own video start time when loop play
  var endSeconds = data[i].attributes[5].nodeValue;     // set your own video end time when loop play
  playerConfigList[i] = ({
      height: '300',
      width: '300',
      videoId: videoId,
      playerVars: {
          autoplay: 0,            // Auto-play the video on load
          controls: 2,            // Show pause/play buttons in player
          showinfo: 0,            // Hide the video title
          modestbranding: 1,      // Hide the Youtube Logo
          fs: 1,                  // Hide the full screen button
          cc_load_policy: 0,      // Hide closed captions
          iv_load_policy: 3,      // Hide the Video Annotations
          start: startSeconds,
          end: endSeconds,
          autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
      },
      events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onStateChange       // reference to Iframe API
          //onReady: function(e) {              // mute the video when loaded
          //e.target.mute();             
          //}
      }
  });
}

var player = [];

// init player
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      player[i] = new YT.Player('player'+(i+1), playerConfigList[i]);
  }
}

var iframes=[];

function onPlayerReady(event){
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if((data[i].attributes[0].nodeValue).localeCompare('player'+(event.target.f.dataset.playid)) == 0)
    {
      iframes[i] = data[i];
      setupListener(event);
    }
  }
}

var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
function setupListener (event){
    for(i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++){
      if((data[i].attributes[0].nodeValue).localeCompare('player'+(event.target.f.dataset.playid)) == 0)
      {
        allButtons[event.target.f.dataset.playid].addEventListener('click', playFullscreen(event));
      }
    }
}

var reqFullScreenArray=[];
function playFullscreen (event){
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if((data[i].attributes[0].nodeValue).localeCompare('player'+(event.target.f.dataset.playid)) == 0)
    {
      player[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1].playVideo(); //won't work on mobile
      console.log(player[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1]);

      reqFullScreenArray[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1] = iframes[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1].requestFullScreen || iframes[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1].mozRequestFullScreen || iframes[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1].webkitRequestFullScreen;

      if(reqFullScreenArray[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1]) {
        reqFullScreenArray[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1].bind(iframes[event.target.f.dataset.playid-1])();
      }
    }
  }
}

function onStateChange(state) {
    if (state.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
    {
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      {
        if(state['target'].f.attributes[0].nodeValue.localeCompare(player[i].f.id) == 0)
        {
          player[i].loadVideoById({
              videoId: playerConfigList[i].videoId,
              startSeconds: playerConfigList[i].playerVars.start,
              endSeconds: playerConfigList[i].playerVars.end
          });
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me correct my code or find another solution, the truth is I am just learning javascript and I have rooted everything. Beforehand thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one iframe that you show and hide as needed. If someone presses a button, you can change the src attribute of the iframe.

Don't forget that iframes slow down your site.